# Terminal Minimizes immediately- unable to maximize

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, windows-10, minimize

I have a Windows 10 machine and dual boot with Ubuntu- not super familiar with all the ins and outs but I've been using Ubuntu for a year now with virtually no problems until recently. In the last three months I've had this issue with the terminal in which I open it and it immediately minimizes. I can try to drag it larger but it shrinks back to minimized and will not open further. This happens about 50% of the time. At first it seemed like it was occurring when I had another program opened already like Chrome, but it also occurs when no other programs are open. I have to close the terminal and open it again to get a normal working terminal. Has anyone experienced this/does anyone know how to fix this bug? Thanks.

[image: Terminal minimized in top left corner-unable to maximize.]

Comment: Have you installed any window customization programs in the last 3 months? On a side note you've been a member in AU for 2 years and 2 months with a reputation of 1. Now it's 6 :D

Comment: No, I don't believe so.  And yeah, I'm not very active haha.

Comment: You mentioned you are using Windows 10 but, I think that is irrelevant in this situation. What version of Ubuntu are you running? When you finally get the terminal open, move to the top line where it says `terminal` and a menu appears. Click on `help` then `about`. What version of `gnome-terminal` does it report? ie mine is 3.18.3.

Comment: I wonder if these tips will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477435/window-appears-off-screen-on-ubuntu Press `Alt`+`Tab` to highlight the terminal window. Press `Alt`+`SpaceBar` and then `down arrow` and then `M` to move. Then use arrow keys to move terminal window back into full view (hopefully). That said I have no clue what is happening to you and hope someone has an answer. I'd be tempted to install Ubuntu all over again  myself if the problem really bugged me.